# connect to heroku postgres with django on a local host

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

i'm trying to connect to my heroku database with a django app that i first run

with a localhost (i.e. NOT on heroku server yet), but i can't get it to work..

i downloaded the psycopg2 via pip command, and i have the next settings of the

database:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'host',   
        'PORT': 'port', 
    }
}
```

when i run: manage.py runserver localhost:8000

i get the following error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module:
DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

so i added: import psycopg2

i ran: manage.py runserver localhost:8000

and got the next error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'CTFdj.settings' (Is it on sys.path?  
Is there an import error in the settings file?): DLL load failed: The     
specified module could not be found.
```

can someone help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: Did you tried that in virtual environment ?

Comment: Where did your add line "import psycopg2"?

Comment: Are you using virtualenv, is that where postgresql is installed? If unsure, can you please update your question with a link to the full traceback (the exception with stack)?

Comment: i'm not using virtual environment, but i added the psycopg2 to the requirements file.  i added "import psycopg2" before the definition of the databse.